# implement crossroads logic in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to write a programm, that checks if a car is allowed to drive/turn on a crossroads.
The cars are identified by colors (e.g. blue, grey, red), the positions of the cars are defined by compass direction (north, east, south, west).
the function to check if allowed to drive is `allow(Color).` (e.g. `allow(blue).`)

This is my actual code:

```
% crossroads priority check

% define cars, positions, and directions 
% carPosition(Color, Position, Direction).

% Case A
carPosition(blue, north, right).
carPosition(red, east, straight).
carPosition(grey, west, left).

% define right and straight neighbours
% neighbours(Position, RightNeighbour, StraightNeighbour).
neighbours(north, west, south).
neighbours(west, south, east).
neighbours(south, east, north).
neighbours(east, north, west).

% check if turn is allowed
allowed(Color) :-

% Check right turns
    carPosition(Color, _, right);

% Check left turns
    (carPosition(Color, Position, left),
    neighbours(Position, RightNeighbour, StraightNeighbour),
    aggregate_all(count, carPosition(_, StraightNeighbour, _), CountStraight),
    aggregate_all(count, carPosition(_, RightNeighbour, _), CountRight),
    (CountStraight + CountRight) < 1 );

% Check straight turns
    (carPosition(Color, Position, straight),
    neighbours(Position, RightNeighbour, _),
    aggregate_all(count, carPosition(_, RightNeighbour, _), CountRight),
    (CountRight < 1 )).
```

In this example (Case A) the answers for `allow(red).` and `allow(grey).` are as expected

> false.

But the `allow(blue).` returns:

> true;
> false.

Where is this false came from and how to avoid it?

Comment: Spurious choice-point?

Comment: Maybe a general problem of my understanding of prolog. But how to make it better/right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comments pretty much hint the problem. You define a car to be alĺowed if it can either go right, go left, or go straight.

In case of `allow(red)` and `allow(grey)` all of these options are checked, all of them are wrong, thus false is printed immediately.

In case of `allow(blue)`, the first option is checked first and it evaluates to true, which is printed. However, this time Prolog knows that there are options that are not checked yet and waits for you to request further computation.

Prolog then checks the second two options, which evaluate to false because the blue car neither wants to go left nor straight.

Since Prolog can't know that every car only ever has one directional wish, it cannot abort the computation after the first result because in other circumstances, additional solutions are required.

There are two easy way to fix this:

- Use the [cut-goal (!)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(logic_programming)) after each option. Please be aware that this might change the semantics (compare red vs. green cut in the link). In your case it's a red cut because it changes the semantics.

  ```
  % Check right turns
  carPosition(Color, _, right),!;
  % Check left turns
  (carPosition(Color, Position, left),!,…
  ```

  After that, the query `allowed(X).` will produce one result at most. This behavior is most likely not wanted.
- Use the cut operator in your query. The advantage of this is that it is not changing the program itself, and it lets the user of the predicate decide whether to request more than one answer.

  ```
  allowed(blue),!.
  ```

PS: There seems to be a snytax error in your program. I had to remove a bracket in the first `allowed` goal.

Comment: perfect, many thanks for the detailed explanation. And a big sorry for the bracket that was to much. I guess that was a kind of that reason, but I'm new in prolog.

Comment: now if I use ´´´allow(Color).´´´ it works for each case. But in the case I use ´´´allow(X).´´´ and there is more than one car allowed to drive of course it stops after the first color. But to correct that I think a complete different kind of logic is needed. correct?

Comment: I wouldn't change the logic, but rather the let the user decide (either in a query or inside another predicate). This way you can offer the same predicate for proofing and for unification.

Comment: thanks again. sounds logic since I sleep over it for a night.